# find function in mongodb and literal objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use Mongoose on nodeJS and I have the following schema in MongoDB:

```
var users = new Schema({
    local:  {
        user_uuid:       String
        ,user_name:      String
        ,password:       String
        ,email:          String
        ,connectionKey:  String
    }
});
```

And I'm exporting the schema in the following way:

```
module.exports.users = mongoose.model('users',users);
```

and this is my find statment:

```
var AllSchemas = require('../schemas/schemas');
...
AllSchemas.users.find({ user_uuid: doctorId},function(err,obj){
   ...
}
```

but I get that the user is not found.
If I take all the parameters out of the literal object "local" it will work
I want to know how can I find things inside a literal object.

Comment: Perhaps the "correct" way of doing this is to have a unique constraint on the data, search on these subfields and then compare.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to reach inside of embedded documents in your query:

```
AllSchemas.users.find({ 'local.user_uuid': doctorId }, function(err,obj) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't deal with lists of objects very well. I ended up having to use e.g. `a.b.0.d`.

Answer (score 0):

While referring to a sub object in the schema, you should use the dot notation inside quotes.
Please refer the following link to get the more information about the dot notation

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation

In your case, you should use:

*AllSchemas.users.find({ 'local.user_uuid': doctorId},function(err,obj){
   ...
}*

This query will return you all the documents having user_uuid equal to doctorId.